# Norton Alert on Java script : Web Attack: Fake Tech Support Website 374

Tags: javascript

I used JavaScript function to get browser information.I added this code :

```
isIEedge = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
```

It has trouble with Norton Anti-virus, I am interested to know why? Here is the alert displayed by Norton Anti-virus :[image]